# Python melt and concat of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, melt

|Practice| Geo   | Country | Details | Jan | Feb | March| 1Q20| April | May | June | 2Q20 |Year| id|

|Cont    |America|Chile    |Cost     |20   |30   |40    |90   |50     |60   |70    |180   |2020| 1 |

|Des     |America|Chile    |Cost     |21   |31   |41    |93   |51    |61   |71    |183   |2020| 1 |

|MJX     |America|Chile    |Cost     |22   |32   |42    |96   |52     |62   |72    |182   |2020| 1 |

|PM      |America|Chile    |Cost     |23   |33   |43    |99   |53     |63   |73    |189   |2020| 1 |

|Vid     |America|Chile    |Cost     |24   |34   |44    |102  |54     |64   |74    |192   |2020| 1 |

Above is the source table and I the output to be with columns as:
Practice |Geo |Country |Details | Month| Month amount | Quarter | Quarter_amount |id |

My approach was to do double melt and then do concat but during concat I am not getting desired result and getting too many NAN in final table. Desired output screenshot is as under
[image]

snippet from my code is as under:

```
    df1 = subdata2.melt(id_vars=['Practice', 'Geo', 'Country', 'Details','Year', 'id'], 
          value_vars=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', '1Q20', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
          var_name='Month', value_name='Month_amount')
    
    df2= subdata2.melt(id_vars=['Practice', 'Geo', 'Country', 'Details','Year', 'id'], 
          value_vars=['1Q20','2Q20'],
          var_name='Quarter', value_name='Quarter_amount')
    print(subdata2)
    
    df1 = df1.set_index(['Practice', 'Geo', 'Country', 'Details','Year', 'id', df1.groupby(['Practice', 'Geo', 'Country', 'Details','Year', 'id']).cumcount()])
    df2 = df2.set_index(['Practice', 'Geo', 'Country', 'Details','Year', 'id', df2.groupby(['Practice', 'Geo', 'Country', 'Details','Year', 'id']).cumcount()])
    print(df1)
    print(df2)
    df3 = (pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1)
            .sort_index(level=5)
            .reset_index(level=5, drop=False)
        .reset_index())
    print("df3 \n",df3)
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried, and show us what you're getting with it.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit your question.

Comment: @ShadowMitia modified the question

Comment: @ShadowMitia The similar post which you provided is NOT having multiple column issue.

Comment: That wasn't me. If you think that other answer doesn't work for your question, then please explain why. If possible change your question to reflect that.